# Separating orthogonal vectors in $\mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-geometry

Is it possible to partition $\mathbb{C}^2$ into two sets $S$ and $S'$ such that, given any two nonzero orthogonal vectors $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ of $\mathbb{C}^2$, one of them lies in $S$ and the other lies in $S'$?
This is easily true for $\mathbb{R}^2$ (we just need to take $S$ as the union of the first and the third quadrant, plus one of the coordinate axes).

Comment: What about the zero vector?

Comment: If you ignore the zero vector, it suffices to partition $\mathbb{CP}^1$. So you want to partition the Bloch sphere into antipodes, which is easy.

Comment: Good point thanks, I corrected the question. Can you tell me more abouts the partition you mean, please?

Comment: Here's an explicit partition $A\sqcup B=\mathbb{C}^2\setminus\{0\}$ that does the trick: Put $(x,y)$ in $A$ if $|x|>|y|$, or if $|x|=|y|$ and $\operatorname{Re}(x\overline{y})>0$, or if $|x|=|y|$ and $\operatorname{Re}(x\overline{y})=0$ and $\operatorname{Im}(x\overline{y})>0$. Otherwise, put $(x,y)$ in $B$.

Comment: Wouldn't the two vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ both end up in B, in this way?

Comment: No, $(1,0)\in A$ since $|1|>|0|$, whereas $(0,1)\in B$ since $|0|<|1|$.

Comment: @Dustin G. Mixon: This is the first time that I see the "Riemann sphere" called "Bloch sphere".  How is this justified and who is the Bloch in the name that you use? Just curious.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: Ah, I guess "Bloch sphere" is more popular in quantum mechanics. Felix Bloch was a Nobel physics laureate. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere

Comment: @Dustin G. Mixon: Thanks, I suspected this. Physicists generally prefer to re-invent bicycles themselves, instead of reading undergraduate math textbooks:-)

Comment: @Dustin G. Mixon: you are right, thanks a lot!